# How to take browser alert screenshot in selenium while running code on remote machine

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, alert

I am trying to take screenshot of browser alerts.

I have tried using Robot class

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("c:\\localdev\\bla.png"));

The problem is i am running code on remote machine and Robot class captures screenshot of part of my local machine which is currently in focus.
```

Comment: _...I have tried using Robot class..._ what was the result? Where do you need help?

Comment: I was running my code on remote machine so Robot class code captures the screenshot of part on which focus is so it captures my eclipse screen and not the alert

Comment: I think alert is part of window not document.